# Question regarding scipy's label function

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, connected-components

Does somebody know how the [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) function works?  I would like to write a function based on PyTorch tensors that has the same behaviour but I couldn't find a detailed description of the function yet.

Comment: Does the function not work on a PyTorch tensor?

Comment: Also, scipy is open source, you can just go and look at the source code. To learn about the algorithm, search for “connected component analysis”.

Comment: FYI: The definition of the Python function starts at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/eca6a269475dfc7b6a50d68a3f65ca9576b7eddd/scipy/ndimage/_measurements.py#L44, but that just does some preprocessing and calls `_ni_label._label(...)`.  The function that does that actual work in written in [Cython](https://cython.org/), and can be found in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx

Comment: @CrisLuengo The label function takes the input and converts it into a numpy array. Also it requires the input to be located on the cpu. I am trying to implement this algorithm into a network and from my understanding all data of the network has to be located on the gpu and needs to be of the same data type torch tensor. So technically it should not be possible for me to implement this algorithm in my network as it causes the program to crash during backpropagtion. If I am missing something here I would be happy if you could help me out.

Comment: You want connected component analysis as part of a neural net??? How is it differentiable?

Comment: The connected component analysis should be part of the neural network but it shouldn't be differentiable. I would like to implement it as an operation the network undergoes in its last step, deciding whether a pixel needs to be fore- or background. Just like you can add a certain constant number that is not differentiable to your intermediate results in your neural network. I've done the same already with the hysteresis of the canny edge detection searching for relevant pixel in the 3x3 neighborhood.